# trying to add new plugins redirect me to my website home page also server error (403 forbidden) is shown when trying to edit with elementor

Tags: wordpress, plugins, elementor

Sorry for the long title, I just wanted to explain everything clearly so that I can get the help I need. I'm new to WordPress, and this website wasn't developed by me, but I've been put in charge of making some modifications. I have no information about the hosting.

The problem I'm facing is that whenever I try to add new plugins, it always redirects me to my website, even though the link shows: https://my_website.com/wp-admin/plugin-install.php/. I've tried deactivating all the plugins, but I'm still facing the same problem. Another issue is that every time I try to edit the website with Elementor, I get "server error (403 forbidden)". I don't know what might be causing these problems. Please help.

more informations:
i'm using wordpress version : 6.3.1
Elementor version :3.16.5

if you have any suggestions i would totally appreciate it